# Receive FCM Push Notification Multiple time automatically. How to stop it?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am using Firebase in my app for chat. but when I send one message that I receive single notification. it's ok. But after 2-3 minutes I will start receiving all old notifications one by one. here is my code for receiving. I remove all code for notification handling but after that, I still received notification repeatedly:--

```
public class FirebaseNotificationReceiver extends WakefulBroadcastReceiver {
    private final String NOTIFICATION_BODY_KEY = "gcm.notification.body";

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        Log.e("NOTIFICATION RECEIVED", "RECEIVED");
    }
```

in menifest:

```
     <receiver
        android:name=".firebase.FirebaseNotificationReceiver"
        android:exported="true"
        android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND">
        <intent-filter>
            <action         android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
```

Comment: What else you have implemented in `onReceive()` method ? Post a minimum relevant code snippet please

Comment: @Bejan  i used custom firebase receiver  that extends WakefulBroadcastReceiver for receiving notifications.  in onReceive() method, i getting the notification title, messege, notiId etc. and display notification. But i have removed all code but still i face same issue. i have also checked firebase receiver for that but i am faceing same problem on that.

Comment: And are you sure that server doesn't send it multiple times ?

Comment: yes, dam sure. i have double checked on server. i have so confused with that, because when i send notification by firebase console than also it received multiple time. How it is possible?

Comment: Potential solution:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48785262/receiving-the-fcm-notifications-multiple-times-on-nougat