# Receiving the FCM notifications multiple times on Nougat

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am using Firebase push notifications in my app. But when I am sending a notification for some event, I am getting notification's multiple times after 2-3 minutes on **Nougat devices** only. I am getting only a single notification on the devices which are having lower version than Nougat.

I have checked that server is sending only a single notification at a time.
I am having below dependency in my app gradle.

```
compile `com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:11.8.0`
```

And here is the code for FCM Listener:

```
public class MyFcmListenerService extends FirebaseMessagingService {

    @Override
public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {

  }
}
```

In manifest file:

```
<service android:name="com.myApp.test.fcm.MyFcmListenerService">
  <intent-filter>
     <action android:name="com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT" />
   </intent-filter>
</service>
```

Answer (score 5):

This started happening to me when I tried to migrate from old GCM to new FCM.
You need to make sure you remove all GCM related code, including gradle (remove `com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm` ) and Manifest

(remove:

```
<uses-permission android:name="mypackage.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" />

<permission
    android:name="mypackage.permission.C2D_MESSAGE"
    android:protectionLevel="signature" />
```

)

Also make sure you **CLEAN** your project and **REBUILD** it, to remove any cached reference to GCM classes. The last part took me like 2 hours to figure out.
A nice trick can be to find-all (⇧⌘F) "GCM" and see if you get hits from the generated files.

Answer (score 1):

Same thing was happening on me , I tried everything only in vain

Then i realised we were storing all fcm tokens of the android device from start till finish without validating or deleting them

I deleted all fcm tokens and re-logged in my app which inserted a fresh singular token in FCM tokens list in my server's db

It worked fine, I think FCM should invalidate earlier tokens before issuing new ones even across installs , multiple apks, and multiple apk debug sessions

Try to send to only 1 token , also clean build and reinstall your app